# Get immediate subdirectories in ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I'm trying to write a simple ruby script that will copy a file to the immediate subdirectories of a directory. How would I get only the immediate subdirectories?

Comment: You just asked the same question about python. Why would you write two scripts in two languages to do the same thing unless its homework?

Comment: because I wanted to compare the answers by the two different communities.

Comment: this seems like homework to me too!!! haha

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Dir.glob("**/")` will return an array of all paths underneath the current directory. From there you can filter the list and copy a file with `File.copy(from, to)`

Answer (score 69):

Assuming you only wanted the *immediate* subdirectories, you could use `Dir['*/']` (which combines Micheal Sepcot's and glenra's answers).

Comment: whats to "assume"? thats what he asked in the question! +1

Comment: This answer gets all the sub directories only one level deep. The answer by Michael Sepcot will get ALL sub directories under the current.

Comment: @AndrewBullock: When this answer was added, the OP had already accepted an answer that didn't make that assumption.

Answer (score 14):

If you mean to find all the *immediate* subdirectories (just one level below where you are), try this:

```
Dir.chdir("/some/path/you/want/to/check/below")
subdir_list=Dir["*"].reject{|o| not File.directory?(o)}
```

That is: change directory someplace, construct an array of files found there, reject those array elements that aren't directories, and return the resulting culled arrray.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way of dealing with files in Ruby is [`Pathname`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html). It combines class methods from a few file-based modules into one nice-to-use OOP class. So you don't need to pass the value into a method like you'd have to with `Dir` or `File`, you can just call the method on the object itself.

Here's how to print immediate subdirectories:

```
require 'pathname'

puts Pathname('some/directory').children.select(&:directory?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @glenra's answer but without changing the directory permanently (which may cause issues with `pry`):

```
def folders
  Dir.chdir("/some/path/you/want/to/check/below") {
    Dir["*"].reject{|o| not File.directory?(o)}
  }
end

puts folders   # ["all", "the", "folders"]
binding.pry    # yay, works
```