# Rails: load_paths for directory and all subdirectories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, load-path

In environment.rb I can add the line

```
config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/foos )
```

where 'foos' is a folder. This loads all files inside the foos folder. However it doesn't load any of its subdirectories.

If I knew the names of all the subdirectories in the 'foos' folder, this problem would have an easy solution:

```
%W[folder1 folder2 folder2].each { |f| f.config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/foos/#{f} ) }
```

However, I won't always know the names of all folders inside of 'foos'. Is there someway to do this:

```
config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/foos/#{**WILDCARD**} )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this other question has the type of solution you are looking for to get all the sub directories:

[get all of the immediate subdirectories in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800189/get-all-of-the-immediate-subdirectories-in-ruby)

You can use something like the following to point at a particular directory and get a list of all the sub directories of it:

```
Dir['/home/username/Music/*/']
```

This will return an array of all the paths to the sub directories of the Music folder.

Comment: Looks good. Could you help me adapt that method to work with in environment.rb.

For example, Dir.glob("**/") finds all the subdirectories of the *current* directory. I want to point to a different directory whose subdirectories I want to load.

Comment: updated the answer to hopefully help you target a particular directory.